# Letting work laptop and home desktop access each other

Tags: windows-7, permissions, network-shares, user-management

I have a laptop I got from work. Its user belongs to a work domain. At home, I also have a desktop PC, that does not belong to any network. I'd like to let each one access certain folders on the other, so I can easily share files. However, none of them acknowledges the user running on the other, so I can't configure any user specific permissions.

The workarounds I currently have is connecting using RDP, and sharing folders with everyone. Neither is ideal.

My home PC is Win7 ultimate, and the laptop is Win7 enterprise. How can I assign each one's user permissions on the other PC?

Answer (score 1):

If you [map a drive to a network share](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Create-a-shortcut-to-map-a-network-drive), you should get the option to connect using different credentials.  At that point, use the username / password for the target machine.

Another option would be to use [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com), which although limited to 2GB in the free version would give you the added benefit of not having to manually copy the files across, as well as accessing the files while outside your home network (e.g. at work).

Answer (score 0):

I thik you should ask this in SuperUser.com

To accomplish this task you have to create a local user in the domain computer called exactly the user in the other PC.

Answer (score 0):

There is an new, still beta, way to do this: with [Chrome browser Remote Desktop plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp). I am not sure whether you can transfer files directly from one pc to the other, but having access to all the apps and filesystem of each pc gives other options: email, ftp etc

Answer (score 0):

Windows Live Mesh will let you share folders and sync them between machines, but your IT people probably won't be too happy about you doing that.  It's works wonderfully and once you set it up, you can share the same folder and it just replicates between to machines as needed.